# Search Stored Procedure (SQL Server) -- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string -- Simple?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I pass 3 variables `bankNumber`, `branchNumber` and `DateFrom` to.

Based on these variables I want to query the table (seen in picture below stored procedure) to return all records that meet the criteria I pass (through variables).

Instead I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

It seems to be failing when I pass it the `DateFrom` variable.

Thank you for your help

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_Records] 
    @bankNumber varchar(3),
    @branchNumber varchar(3),
    @dateCreated datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE 
        @Bank_Number varchar(3) = @bankNumber,
        @Branch_Number varchar(3) = @branchNumber,
        @DateFrom datetime = @dateCreated,
        @DateTo datetime = @dateCreated

    SELECT DISTINCT     
        A.bankNumber, 
        A.branchNumber, 
        A.dateCreated
    FROM        
        dbo.CENSORED A
    WHERE
        (@Branch_Number IS NULL OR bankNumber LIKE @BankNumber + '%')
        AND (@Branch_Number IS NULL OR branchNumber LIKE @Branch_Number + '%')
        AND (@DateFrom IS NULL OR dateCreated LIKE + @DateFrom + '%')
        AND (@DateTo IS NULL OR dateCreated LIKE + @DateTo + '%')
  END
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: @JohnConde sql server thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What do you mean by `@DateFrom + '%'` ? Matching Month? Matching Day? Matching Year? Matching hours?..............

Comment: @M.Ali I'm trying to match only the month. Thank you for your question.

Comment: Also where did the `@dateCreated` come from ?

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` on a `DATETIME` - either convert the `DATETIME` to a string (using `CAST` or `CONVERT`) and then apply the `LIKE`, or change your search to something else

Comment: @M.Ali check under ALTER PROCEDURE. Thanks.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for editing my post further, I will attempt your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `LIKE` operator with Datetime value. If you are matching only on month you would need to use `MONTH()` function. `LIKE` operator can only be used with string data types.

Dont see the point of all these Variables declared in your stored procedure, a simplified version should look something like ....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_Records] 
    @bankNumber varchar(3),
    @branchNumber varchar(3),
    @dateCreated datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT     
        A.bankNumber, 
        A.branchNumber, 
        A.dateCreated
    FROM        
        dbo.CENSORED A
    WHERE
            (@Branch_Number IS NULL OR bankNumber   LIKE @bankNumber + '%')
        AND (@Branch_Number IS NULL OR branchNumber LIKE @branchNumber + '%')
        AND (@dateCreated   IS NULL OR (MONTH(dateCreated) = MONTH(@dateCreated) 
                                         AND 
                                        YEAR(dateCreated) = YEAR(@dateCreated)))

END
```

*Note*

this will produce a very inefficient execution plan, consider using dynamic sql for queries with optional parameters like this one.

Comment: my apologies I know I misinformed you earlier I meant I'm trying to match this format MM/DD/YY

Comment: `MM/DD/YY` is a string representation of a datetime value. Your column and variable both are of Datetime datatype which is good. you just need to use Convert function in your select to get the desired date format, which I think should be `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), A.dateCreated, 1)`

Comment: I'm going to implement this now, and see how it goes. I'll brb. Thank you!